# Is it possible to track geolocation with a service worker while PWA is not open

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

Is it possible to read from local storage and track geolocation in PWAs with a service worker while app is not open on phone (in background)

So far my research is pointing to no, and I am finding that the PWA needs to be open for location services.

Thank you,

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution is at hand and has been for some years now as this [POC](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen) clearly testifies. Unfortunately W3C have fought tooth and nail to prevent it from being made available :-(

Why? I know not. The "cui bono" argument points to plug-in vendors such as Ionic whose whole raison d'etre appears to be background geolocation.

See this [link](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745) for complete story.

Comment: Thank you for the info, read a few things about this prior and was hoping there was more movement for it cause the articles that I read were older and PWA concept seems to be a fast changing landscape at this point.

Comment: Please contribute to https://github.com/w3c/geolocation-api/issues/74

Comment: If every installed service worker could track a person's movement wither the client page/app was open or not, that would be a serious privacy intrusion. You'd need a permissions flow before you could even think of doing that and you'd probably want app permissions to be visible from a device's permissions page.

Comment: Are there any news on this? I don't understand why this is such a big argument, specially with the line between PWA and native apps getting more and more blurry... I am developing a mountaineering PWA which is going to have to have background location recording pretty soon...
If there is a still open Github issue on which I could make my voice heard I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: @McMurphy I would lika a clarification, do you mean that you can use Ionic in a PWA to get background geolocation? I have no experience with Ionic and I can't find that this is possible without building a native app in the documentation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the PhoneGap-esque products have their own browser running within a native app with access to native APIs that PWAs do not. But I have not tried. Others may have had more fruitful experiences but sadly PWAs are still deprive of this water shed functionality for no good reason.